# Duda en Herencia de clases en Python

Tags: python, clase, herencia, constructor

Tengo esta clase enemigo, que tendra tipo de enemigo y tipo de ataque con sus getters, setters y deleters y ademas sus metodos

```
class Enemigo():

def __init__(self, tipo, ataque):
 self._tipo = tipo
 self._ataque = ataque 

@property 
def tipo(self):
 return self._tipo

@tipo.setter
def tipo(self, tipo):
 self._tipo = tipo

@tipo.deleter
def tipo(self):
 del self._tipo

@property 
def ataque(self):
 return self._ataque

@ataque.setter
def ataque(self, ataque):
 self._ataque = ataque

@ataque.deleter
def ataque(self):
 del self._ataque 

def atacar():
 print(f'{self._tipo} ha atacado con {self._ataque}')
```

ahora voy a crear la clase de Zombi y Vampiro que seran los tipos de enemigos que heredaran de la clase Enemigo

```
class Zombi(Enemigo):
 def __init__(self):
 super().__init__('Zombie', 'Bendaje sangriento')
```

ahora lo que no comprendo es que en esta clase Zombi, no se deberian colocar en el constructor de la misma todos los atributos para que los herede? como sale en el ejemplo de abajo

```
class Zombi(Enemigo):
 def __init__(self, tipo, ataque):
 Enemigo.__init__(tipo, ataque)
```

Ademas no entiendo esta linea de codigo

```
 super().__init__('Zombie', 'Bendaje sangriento')
```

que es lo que esta tratando de hacer? ahi?

Comment: El `super` inicializa todas las clases padres, es muy útil cuando se trabaja con herencia múltiple, pues te evita de estar haciendo `Enemigo__init__(); Enemigo2.__init__(); Enemigo3.__init__() ...` Con respecto a tu primera duda no la entiendo bien. Si tu quieres puedes hacer `def __init__(self, tipo, ataque): super().__init__(tipo, ataque)` y listo. Recuerda que los argumentos del `__init__` serán los que necesites para crear una nueva instancia de la clase

Comment: lo que no entiendo es por que se le pasaron los atributos de la clase de una vez en el  super de la clase Zombi  @Christian

Comment: Por que son necesarios para inicializar la clase. Quitalos y verás un error